# Mac OS VSCode Connection error while attempting to download client ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/kubectl')

Tags: azure, macos, visual-studio-code, azure-cli

After running this command in vscode on MacOS:

`az aks install-cli`

I get this error:

`Connection error while attempting to download client ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/kubectl')`

I don't know how to fix this, if someone could help I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

add `sudo` at the beginning of your command line.

This will ask for your Machine User password.

Comment: Thanks it fixed that error but now I get this: Downloading client to "/usr/local/bin/kubectl" from "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.23.1/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl"
Please ensure that /usr/local/bin is in your search PATH, so the `kubectl` command can be found.
Downloading client to "/tmp/tmp57q9_mlx/kubelogin.zip" from "https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/releases/download/v0.0.10/kubelogin.zip"
Please ensure that /usr/local/bin is in your search PATH, so the `kubelogin` command can be found.

Comment: Please try following this guide (make sure you select Apple Silicon for non-Intel MacOS): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/

Comment: Hi I already followed the guide and installed it with homebrew but it still isn't working

Comment: What happened after you ran `brew install kubectl`?

Comment: Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/kubectl
Target /usr/local/bin/kubectl
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/kubectl'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run kubernetes-cli

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/kubectl -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl

Comment: It says: **`/usr/local/bin/kubectl` already exists**. If you get an error running `kubectl version --client`. Then **overwrite it by running `brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli`**.

Comment: Being on M1 silicon I've managed to get `az aks install-cli` working by removing kubectl with brew: `brew uninstall kubectl`, and installing manually with curl following the official guide: `kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos`, thx @PierreJanineh for the tip!